# How to get multiple fields values by condition in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table  with following fields and values
for example 
table fields (ABC ,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO)
Values (YES,NO,YES,YES,NO)

now the question is that how to select all those  fields whose values are "YES"?

thnx.....

Comment: you need to create dynamic sql on this. (*which is not simple*)

Comment: since you are using it, why dont simply use PHP ?? `select all -> foreach -> if this_value = yes, then return the key(field name) ?`

Comment: is this table used for keeping configuration variables and values? if yes I suggest you instead of creating several fields, just create two columns "key" and "value" then all config data stored in rows. Much better practice if this table is for config variables

Comment: Columns / Fields, not Rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may parse columns in PHP:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `tablename`');

if($result->num_rows){
    $row    = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $buffer = array();

    foreach($row as $key => $value){
         if($value == 'Yes')$buffer[] = $key;
    }

} else {
    echo 'no rows';
}

$result->free();

var_dump($buffer);
```

Comment: This statement is equivalent to `... WHERE abc = 'YES' and def = 'YES' and ...'. It's not a right answer to the question asked.

Comment: @currupt this will retrieve the record if all the field values are "YES" otherwise this will shows the empty result.... this is not my question

Comment: @user2118352 , yeah.. I'm finally figured what you want... fixing